# Query to get records which "all" documents have a certain value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm having problem framing a query for the below:

```
{ "dg" : "dg4", "r": -1 }
{ "dg" : "dg4", "r": -1}

{ "dg" : "dg3", "r":-1}
{ "dg" : "dg3", "r":-1}

{ "dg" : "dg2", "r": -1}
{ "dg" : "dg2", "r":100}

{ "dg" : "dg1", r:200}
{ "dg" : "dg1", r:201}

{ "dg" : "dg0", "r":-1}
{ "dg" : "dg0", "r":-1}
{ "dg" : "dg0", "r":2}
```

Now I want to query grouped by each "dg" and make sure ALL it's "r" is -1 else don't return that dg.
In the above example, I want "dg4" and "dg3" since both dg3,dg4 have "all" $r as -1.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to compare the "sets" after they are constructed. So [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and then [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) where the elements contain anything else than the required value:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$dg",
    "rValues": { "$push": "$r" }
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$eq": [ { "$size": { "$setDifference": [ "$rValues", [-1] ] } }, 0 ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }   
 }}
])
```

If you really were not interested in the "full" set of values then you could [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) instead to keep the array size down.

But it's the [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) to the expected comparison of `[-1]` as the only values which decides what gets returned.

Which gives the results from above as:

```
{
    "_id" : "dg4",
    "rValues" : [ 
        -1.0, 
        -1.0
    ]
}


{
    "_id" : "dg3",
    "rValues" : [ 
        -1.0, 
        -1.0
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have maybe a trick you can use for the example you give.

You have to exclude results when at least one `r` is different to `-1` I understand.

So why not doing like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: "$dg",
        rm: {$min: "$r"}, // get minimum value of all r of the same dg
        rM: {$max: "$r"} // get maximum value of all r of the same dg
    }},
    {$match: {
        rm: {$ne: -1}, // filter out when other value than -1
        rM: {$ne: -1} // filter out when other value than -1
    }}
]);
```

And so, you exclude all values which don't have minimum and maximum r equals to `-1`; so excluding all witch have at least one `r` value at different number than `-1`.

I hope I helped you ;)